# ColdFusion form and session variable setting

Tags: coldfusion

I have a checkbox inside of a form tag and I basically want to persist the checked state of the checkbox using a session. Apparently I'm doing it wrong because whenever I reload the page it sets the session back to off(which is the default value for the checkbox param). Here is the code i'm using.

Form:

```
<cfform name="matureContent" method="post" action="/index.cfm?fuseaction=main.Channels_Detail&c=#URL.c#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <cfif SESSION.matureSession eq "on">
      <input name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      <cfelse>
      <input name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
      </cfif>
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </cfform>
```

Session variable and params if they are not present on page load.

```
    <cfparam name="form.myCheckbox" default="off">
<cfparam name="SESSION.maturesession" default="off">
<cfset SESSION.maturesession = form.myCheckbox>
```

If i'm going about this completely the wrong way let me know. Thanks.

Comment: are you using `<cflocation />` after the code block used to set the session? If so, that's the problem. See this tech note: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/181/tn_18171.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `<cfparam name="form.myCheckbox"
>   default="off">
>
>   <cfparam name="SESSION.maturesession"
>   default="off">
>
>   <cfset SESSION.maturesession =
>   form.myCheckbox>`

I think that will result in overwriting the saved value if you return to the page from somewhere else. Instead, try updating the session value only when the form was submitted. Also, since you are using a cfform you could shortcut things by using `yes/no` instead of `on/off`.

**Update** I forgot the cfparam for the session variable. But if you truly want to carry it throughout the session, you could also initialize it `onSessionStart` instead.

```
<cfparam name="SESSION.maturesession" default="no">
<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "submit")>
    <cfparam name="form.myCheckbox" default="no">
    <cfset SESSION.maturesession = form.myCheckbox>
</cfif>

<cfform name="test" method="post" ....>
    <cfinput name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="yes" checked="#session.matureSession#" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</cfform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have sessions turned on?

You have to explicitly turn on sessions for your app using the [CFAPPLICATION](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_a-b_5.html) tag if you're using Application.cfm, or, if you're using Application.cfc, by setting this.sessionManagement = true.

Application.cfm:

```
<cfapplication 
  name = "application name"
  applicationTimeout = #CreateTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)#
  sessionManagement = "yes"
  sessionTimeout = #CreateTimeSpan(0,0,20,0)#>
```

Application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
  <!--- Application name, should be unique --->
  <cfset this.name = "ApplicationName">
  <!--- How long application vars persist --->
  <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)>
  <!--- Should we even use sessions? --->
  <cfset this.sessionManagement = true>
  <!--- How long do session vars persist? --->
  <cfset this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,0,20,0)>
</cfcomponent>
```

OK, then if sessions ARE turned on, when you submit the form, what does the code look like that you're posting the form to?

Comment: Sessions are turned on and working, but whenever i leave the page and come back the session is being changed back to the default param.

Comment: When you submit the form, what does the code look like that you're posting the form to?  Are you setting the session variables in the main.Channels_Detail template?

Comment: In my original post I included the form code and how the session is receiving its value.

Comment: Oh, missed the last line.  So, the code you're posting to is the 2nd code block?